# What does “something in white canvas, has long sleeves and ties in the back“ mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm watching Baywatch season 5 episode 12.

> C.J.: Well, if there can be aliens, why can't there be elves?
>   Matt: C.J., You've been a big help. Now I know what to get you for Christmas.
>   C.J.: Really? What?
>   Matt: **Something in white canvas, has long sleeves and ties in the back.**

I don't know the meaning of Matt's last sentence.
I would be grateful if someone helps me understand the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a joke. It sounds like Matt is describing a straitjacket, and therefore, suggesting that CJ is “crazy”. A “crazy” person would believe in aliens and elves.

[image]